# InvalidArgumentException: Given $key is in an invalid state. Can only lookup records when given a complete key. Given path was [ [user: ] ]

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

The code does not work when i'm trying to retrieve the entites stored in name.php. It throws the above error.

name.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION["username"] . "!    ";

    if(isset($_POST['but_change'])) { 

       if($_SESSION["pass"] == $_POST['oldpwd']) {

            $key= $datastore -> key('user', $_SESSION["id"]);
            $entity = $transaction -> lookup($key);
            echo $entity;
       }
        else echo 'User password is incorrect';
    }
   ?>
```

login.php

```
$projectId = "s3764073-task2";
$datastore = new DatastoreClient([ 'projectId' => $projectId]);


      $key = $datastore->key('user', $_POST['uname']);
      $entity = $datastore->lookup($key);

      $_SESSION["id"]= $_POST['uname'];
      $_SESSION["username"] = $entity['name'];
      $_SESSION["pass"] = $entity['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

according to ['Retrieveing an entity'](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity), I think you are missing the initialization of the transaction:

```
$transaction = $datastore->transaction();
```

I think adding this should work.

//--EDIT
According to [github example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/datastore/api/src/functions/concepts.php), you should initialize the Datastore client:

```
function initialize_client()
{
    $datastore = new DatastoreClient();
    return $datastore;
}
```

Comment: I added the above statement and now it says :
"PHP Notice: Undefined variable: datastore " for the above line

AND

"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function transaction() on a non-object "

Comment: Taking a look into the [github example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/datastore/api/src/functions/concepts.php), there is missing also the `initialize_client()`. I have edited the answer.